# Can't align table properly

Tags: html, reactjs

I just started learning ReactJS recently, and making small progress at a time. One of the exercise that I'm working on now wants me to align value and its number properly, but it seems that I'm having an issue with it. Following are my code (note: I have only posted relevant parts that displays table):

```
const Statistic = ({text, value, postfix}) => (
    <table >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{text}</td>
                <td style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{value} {postfix}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

Which is used in Statistics:

```
const Statistics = ({good, neutral, bad}) => {
    if((good + neutral + bad) > 0) { 
        return (
            <div>
                <Statistic text="good" value={good} />
                <Statistic text="neutral" value={neutral} />
                <Statistic text="bad" value={bad} />

                <Statistic text="all" value={good + neutral + bad}/>                
                <Statistic text="average" value={(good - bad) / (good + neutral + bad)}/> 
                <Statistic text="positive" value={100 * (good / (good + neutral + bad)) } postfix="%"/>
            </div>
        )
    }

    return(<div>No feeback given</div>)
}
```

which is then used in App to render them. My output is following:

[image]

Red rectangle indicates how it should be aligned. I did manage to clear out the warning on console regarding to `<tbody>` as well as found some information online about using `style={{}}` to align the table, but it does not seem to work. I would love any feedback and/or advice on how to fix this issue. Thank you in advance!

Comment: This probably has nothing to do with styling. A normal table would align the columns accordingly. Doesn't this code generate a new table everytime? If you inspect the table, do you see multiple tables in your inspector?

Comment: That was a good catch! it is absolutely generating new table each time. Threw lots of warning again, but it definitely went to right direction. Thank you for your help!! :)

Comment: You have to put the table and tbody outside of it. You dont want that generated for every value you generate

Comment: Fixed. Thank you for your answer, you were right on point in terms of where the issue was!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this:

```
const Statistic = ({text, value, postfix}) => (
    <table >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>{text}</td>
                <td style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{value} {postfix}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
)
```

, it generates a new `table` and `tbody` for every record. You only want this in it:

```
const Statistic = ({text, value, postfix}) => (
            <tr>
                <td>{text}</td>
                <td style={{textAlign: 'right'}}>{value} {postfix}</td>
            </tr>
)
```

And then put the

```
<table >
   <tbody>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

somewhere where it wont render more than once. And then put the result of Statistic in between the tbody tags.